# mangento in postgres or oracle database?

Tags: oracle, magento, e-commerce

i need an open source ecommerce solution, i think magento is an excellent ecommerce solution but i can't use mysql because is a customer requirement and magento only offer mysql database support.

any tips to setup magento in postgres or oracle ?.

thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that it would be reliable as the solution for several reasons:

a) Usually magento dev team upgrade their mysql db tables almost in every release (without proper documentation) so you will be forced to upgrade manually your db structure after every change (it's not wise to ignore magento upgrades, since they fix pretty big list of bugs everytime (and introduce some new bugs long the way :P)).

b) Magento's db structure is very complex, and it would be an hellish job to port everything in another type of DBMS with it's own reasonings for external keys and such

c) And in the last: I'm not sure that their db engine would support a new kind of DBMS (it should be Zend_Db but who knows).

I'd suggest you to convince client in using mysql (since you would need dedicated server anyway for running smoothly magento)

Comment: Using ORM tool would make things much smoother for multi-DB support, unfortunately many projects don't consider that when they start. That's a pity, because there are better DBs than MySql and sometimes the client has a DB setup already which they don't like to change.

Answer (score 0):

Alekc is absolutely right, porting to another db is infeasible. I'm not sure what reasons your client has for not wanting MySQL, but perhaps if spending money puts them at ease they could purchase the MySQL Enterprise license which includes full support: [MySQL Enterprise](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/)

Comment: It's not about spending, I'd say it's about the current setup, DB administration and introducing another DB engine in the company which is (naturally) being avoided if possible.

Comment: You can't imagine why a person would not want MySQL near their organization?

Answer (score 0):

If you must have Postgresql, give Bitcommerce a look. As far as I know, it is the only feature complete eCommerce solution with total Postgres support.

https://github.com/bitweaver/bitcommerce

Answer (score -2):

You can learn here about the "enterprise" features of magento - as usual in the php world, this word is used as a pure marketing term, not backed by anything.

If you take a closer look, you will see many very strange things happening in magento, which are typical for php developers which do not want to take a look what is happening outside of their ghetto.

I reccomend using a modern python webframework and build your system on postgresql and not rely on magento code, if you do not absolutely need to do it. This will save you a lot of pain and money. You will, in the end, be very happy not having to rely on php developers that do not seem to understand what "enterprise" really makes people expect.